# Countable Union of an Infinite Set Equivalence

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Assuming the link: [Infinite set as union of disjoint countable sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262988/infinite-set-as-union-of-disjoint-countable-sets) implies the following proposition:

**Prop:** *If $\{A_i:i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a collection of disjoint infinite sets of the same cardinality, then
$$|\cup_i A_i|=|A_1|.$$*
I would like to show it implies the next claim below. Given two sets $A$ and $B$, we define
$$|A|\cdot |B|:=|A\times B|.$$
**Claim:** *If $T$ is an infinite set, then
$$\aleph_0\cdot |T|=|T|.$$*

Comment: The linked answer implies the latter claim, although both are true

Comment: @DonThousand - I have edited my question since you mentioned both results are true. I am now more curious if the former latter result (my prop) can be used to imply my former first result (the claim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\aleph_0 \times T$ *is* a countable collection of disjoint sets of the same cardinality, ( $A_i = \{i\} \times T$ ).

Comment: Could you clarify? Also, did I misinterpret $\aleph_0\cdot |T|$? Should this be something like $|\mathbb{N}\times T|$?

Comment: @northcity4: Given your definition, $\aleph_0\cdot|T|=|\aleph_0\times T|$. Whether $\aleph_0=\Bbb N$ or merely has the same cardinality depends on your definitions; for me $\aleph_0=\Bbb N$, so $$\aleph_0\cdot|T|=|\Bbb N\times T|=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}(\{n\}\times T)\,,$$ where the sets $\{n\}\times T$ clearly all have cardinality $|T|$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So would a solution look like this: Using $\mathbb{N}$ as our set of size $\aleph_0$ and $A_i$ as in David's answer, we have that $|\cup_i A_i|=|\mathbb{N}\times T|$ since the identity function is a bijection and $|\cup_i A_i|=|T|$ as a consequence of Zorn's lemma (proposition at top)?

Comment: @northcity4: I was simply using the prop. at the top, since I didn’t know how you proved it, but yes, that’s exactly what I was suggesting.

Comment: @Brian: While formally not incorrect, it is **very** bad form to write $\aleph_0\times T$ when considering $\Bbb N\times T$, or $\omega\times T$.