# An infinite set can be written as the countably infinite union of pairwise disjoint infinite sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have been trying to prove this. I came up with two cases. One case where the inifnite set is countable and one where it isn't. For the one that isn't. I said that an infinite set must contain a countably infinite set and that the difference of the original set and this new countably infinite set must be still be uncountable. Therefore, by induction, we can find a pair of disjoint infinite sets. However, I am having trouble proving the union is countably infinite.

For the countable side, I know it should be trivial but my mind is still coming up blank.

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Hint: If $X$ is infinite, then the cardinality of $X$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}\times X$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite set as union of disjoint countable sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262988/infinite-set-as-union-of-disjoint-countable-sets)