# If $X$ is not isomorphic to $Y$ then $ X \times X$ is not isomorphic to $Y \times Y$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have not done math for a long time and I need a little help.

I need to know if it's true that if $X$ is  not isomorphic to $Y$ then $ X \times X$ is not isomorphic to $Y \times Y$ being $X$ and $Y$ vector spaces. I tried trying that if  $ X \times X$ is isomorphic to $Y \times Y$ then $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$ but I do not know how to continue.

If it is true can you help me with the proof? And if it is false  can  you give me an example of vector spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $X$ is not isomorphic to $Y$ but however $ X \times X$ is isomorphic to $Y \times Y$.

Thank you to all.

Comment: Are you in a finite-dimensional situation (much easier) or an infinite dimensional case?

Comment: Actually, the two statements you have are contrapositives of each other, so they're logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed true. Recall that two vector spaces are isomorphic iff the cardinality of their basis coincide.

Let's first treat the finite-dimensional case. Let $n:=dim(X)$ and $m:=dim(Y)$. If $X\times X$ is isomorphic to $Y\times Y$, then we have (using $dim(V\times V)= 2 dim(V)$ for a vector space $V$)

$$ 2n=dim(X\times X) = dim(Y\times Y) = 2m.$$

We get $n=m$ and hence $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic.

The infinite-dimensional case is essentialy the same. We need that the [Cardinality of the Cartesian Product of Two Equinumerous Infinite Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383755/cardinality-of-the-cartesian-product-of-two-equinumerous-infinite-sets) is the same as the infinite set itself. And redo the argument above.

Edit: As pointed out in the comment section the argument is not clear in the infinite-dimensional case. Let $E$ be a basis of an infinite-dimensional vector space $V$. Note that we have

$$\vert E \vert \leq \vert basis \ V\times V\vert= \vert E \ \sqcup E\vert \leq \vert E \times E\vert = \vert E \vert,$$

where the last equality is due to [Cardinality of the Cartesian Product of Two Equinumerous Infinite Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383755/cardinality-of-the-cartesian-product-of-two-equinumerous-infinite-sets). Hence, the dimension of $V$ and $V\times V$ coincide. Thus, if $X\times X$ and $Y\times Y$ have the same dimension, so do $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that $\dim(E\times F)=\dim(E)\times\dim(F)$? What is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @C.Falcon Thanks for pointing out my stupid mistake.

Comment: Note that there is nothing natural about the isomorphism!

Comment: @JJR Is it possible to obtain a natural isomorphism? My feeling is telling my that in the infinite-dimensional case there is no such thing, but what about the finite-dimensional case?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I also don't think so and additionally I am not sure that the argument with the cardinality in infinite dimensional case works since $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ have same cardinality as sets but are not isomorphic over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JJR I'm not applying the cardinality argument to the the spaces, but to their respective basis.

Comment: You probably mean $|\text{Basis of }X| = |\text{Basis of }X\times X|$

Comment: is it really so trivial to prove that $|A\amalg A| = |A|$ for any cardinal $|A|$

Comment: @JJR Do you see any problems with the inequalities above?

Comment: They are definitely correct just not sure if trivial https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198904/cardinality-of-infinite-sets